# Selenium WebDriver wicket FindElement challenges

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, wicket

I am new to Selenium WebDriver but have largely instrumented a Java/Wicket based app.  Unfortunately I am stuck on figuring out how to identify a collection of page navigation controls provided by the Wicket framework.  The controls look like the following:

<< < 1 2 3 4 5 > >>

Using Firebug I can see a href strings that contain dynamic ids and the elements are not named and hence my dilemma.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: post a code sample, please

Comment: A handy tool for Firebug is Firepath which helps you find the Xpath of items on the screen which you can use in your selenium test cases. You can also add Selenium tags in your Java project so the div id will remain constant.

Comment: Addendum:  I have also looked at a clumsy scenario of possibly using the tab order to get to the desired element/control. The desired elements/controls are not included in the tab order.

Comment: Please post the actual HTML of this. Explain what's "dynamic" about them, explain whats "standard"/"static" about them. Explain what versions of browsers you are testing against. Explain what you've tried so far, how they didn't work, why it didn't work and what errors (if any you got).

Comment: <a id="id522" href="?wicket:interface=:30:form:gfis:bottomToolbars:1:toolbar:span:navigator:next::ILinkListener::" onclick="var wcall=wicketAjaxGet('?wicket:interface=:30:form:gfis:bottomToolbars:1:toolbar:span:navigator:next::IBehaviorListener:0:',null,null, function() {return Wicket.$('id522') != null;}.bind(this));return !wcall;"> … </a>

Comment: Above is what Firebug exposes for the control in question, i.e., the 'next' arrow.  What is dynamic is the id.  It gets updated EVERY time the page is refreshed, i.e., not very useful.  Note there is no 'name' defined.

Comment: Your last two comments should really be edits to the above question. The comment section is for discussion. Any new information should be added to the question. It also makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug has a plug-in called FirePath which allows the user to find elements by Xpath. It also allows the user to find an elements XPath. The Xpath can be used in your Selenium test class.

You can also use Selenium tags to add a Div id to an element in your Java. Then use the Div id in your Selenium test cases.

Below is an example of clicking an element by Xpath.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/a[@title='San Jose Sharks']")).click();`

Comment: FirePath looks interesting.  However initial attempt to install seems to be blocked at some level by our IT dept security.  Still working the problem.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Progress.  Got FirePath installed.  Not clear how to access. Guidance online appears to be dated, i.e., describes UI options that I don't see.  Any URL suggestions for getting started?

Comment: +1 for suggestion use of Xpath. I find that xpath expressions are needed to find a lot of the html components generated by Wicket, usually when they have dynamic ids. I've not used FirePath, but I find that inspection of the HTML using Firebug usually helps me to construct the required Xpath expression to locate the element.

Comment: I just installed FirePath. It's accessible from the Firebug panel. Simply navigate to your page, start Firebug and you should see the Firepath menu added to the Firebug panel.

Comment: OK. Operator error on my part plus a configuration fubar.  I made the mistake of letting Firefox update to V24.  Just getting back to working state now and got FirePath working.  Need to spin up on how this works and then the Xpath scenario test can occur.

Comment: I will post a separate question for this but I am having trouble getting Firebug (w/ or w/o FirePath enabled) working.  I am using Firebug V1.73 in order to be compatible w/ Firefox V22 in order to be compatible w/ Selenium Webdriver V2.35.0. I got sidetracked from this effort for a few days and am now back on this in earnest.  I'm not familiar w/ Firebug or FirePath so this seems to be quite the task.

Comment: I was using the wrong version of FirePath.  The correct version is apparently 1.11.4.  That solved the immediate problem but now I see some undesirable side effects of having FirePath and/or FireBug enabled, i.e., navigation in the testing app results in a new instance instead of changing the current instance.  Will disable the add-on's unless I actively using them.

Answer (score 0):

You said that they were  elements?  That should be relatively easy then.

```
int pageNum = 1;//Or whatever number you want to click on
driver.findElement(By.linkText(pageNum+""));
```

If there are other links that contains a number in it (which may be very likely), you can select a parent element:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".pageNumSet")).findElement(By.linkText(pageNum+""));
```

(Obviously the `.pageNumSet` selector will have to change.

(BTW, I don't really recommend XPath unless you absolutely have to use it.  Its the most powerful of all the selectors, but also the slowest.  (Generated XPath can also be very fragile)

Answer (score 0):

The standard wicket id's change with each page render so you can't use them. You can, however, instruct wicket to add a wicketpath attribute to each element (where appropriate - maybe links/buttons only?) and then tell Selenium to use wicketpath instead of wicket id:
http://www.jdev.it/testing-a-wicket-application-with-selenium-ide/

Wicket will only add the 'wicketpath' element in Debug mode so your production website won't lose any performance because it won't have them.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into exactly the same problem with **wicket**. The page change block is 'protected' from scraping by an ever changing **id**, hidden input field in the form, a `jsessionid=BcxrRceaycMF3I0ZgL5lMfHg_tEQ2mIS6IS71m69` in href that you will never see if you don't retrieve it from your headless browser and all the other kindergarten stupidity.

The solution *for this particular case* (because I had it exactly the same and this is a live example):

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/opt/google/chrome/chromedriver',
                           chrome_options=options)

browser.get('https://webapps1.chicago.gov/activegcWeb/')

page_link = browser.find_element_by_link_text('2') # or any other
page_link.click()
```

With this you can scrape all the pages in this pagination menu (and move further with '>'). The trick works well because '2' is a *complete* text of the link; It's hard to imagine that you will have another link like this on your page (besides the lower or upper pagination menu).

There is a variation `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text()` method. And, of course, all the rest, explained with examples here:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Enjoy! :)